# MPMoviePlayerController not staying within bounds of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to add a video to a UIView container within a modal window. When I add the video it does not stay within the bounds of the UIView which it is bounded to. Here is a picture of what it currently looks like:

[image: Current State]

The grey container which you can see the right edge of is the container and here is the view controller which adds the video.

```
import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

class EvalInstructionsVC: UIViewController {
    private var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?

    @IBOutlet weak var video: UIView!

    func playVideo() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Time to Rotate Demo", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = video.bounds
            player.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(video.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(video.bounds))
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
            video.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playVideo()
    }

    @IBAction func done(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

As you can see the bounds are being set and it is being added as a sub view to video UIView which is the grey box in the screenshot above.

I would appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Cheers,
Gerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `player.view.frame = video.bounds` later in the view controller lifecycle.

Simplest solution is to call `playVideo()` from `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    playVideo()
}
```

FYI, our code is so similar (based on the same example?), I think you also probably won't need to set `player.view.center`.

Comment: Yeh that makes sense. I'll try that when I get in. Thanks. The centre part was just me playing around :)